# On searching documents in mongodb collection using ISODate range, I get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

I am trying to query MongoDB using the following -

```
List<BsonDocument> list = NoSqlBusinessEntityBase.LoadByWhereClause("peoplecounting",
    string.Concat("{siteid:\"", siteid, "\", locationid:\"", location._id ,"\",
    StartTime: {$gte:ISODate(\"",old.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"),"\")}, 
    EndTime: {$lte:ISODate(\"",current.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), "\"\")}}"));
```

The LoadByWhereClause() function is as follows -

```
public static List<BsonDocument> LoadDataByWhere(string table, string whereClause)
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection(table);
    QueryDocument whereDoc = new QueryDocument(BsonDocument.Parse(whereClause));
    var resultSet = collection.Find(whereDoc);
    List<BsonDocument> docs = resultSet.ToList();

    if (resultSet.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (BsonDocument doc in docs)
        {
            doc.Set("_id", doc.GetElement("_id").ToString().Split('=')[1]);
        }
        return docs;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even though the query runs fine in MongoDB console and returns documents

```
db.peoplecounting.find({siteid:"53f62abf66455068373665ff", locationid:"53f62bb86645506837366603",
    StartTime:{$gte:ISODate("2012-12-03 02:40:00")}, EndTime:{$lte:ISODate("2013-12-03 07:40:00")}}
```

I get the error when I try to load in C# using the LoadByWhereClause function. The error is `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` while parsing the whereClause.
How can I possibly fix this? I am unable to determine what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not *entirely* clear, but I suspect the problem may well be how you're formatting the date. This:

```
old.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

should almost certainly be this:

```
old.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

or possibly

```
old.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

Because:

- `mm` means minutes. You don't want the minutes value between your year and day-of-month; you want the month (`MM`)
- `hh` means "hour of half-day" (i.e. 1-12). You want the hour of full day, 0-23 (`HH`)
- ISO-8601 uses a `T` literal to separate the date frmo the time.

I note that your `current.ToString` is *better*, but not correct - it gets the month right, but not the hour. The fact that these are inconsistent is a problem to start with - I would advise you to write a separate method to convert a `DateTime` appropriately.

Comment: Tried formatting this way but even that gives me the same exception.

Comment: @Rookie: Do you have an example of the formatted string that fails? Have you tried removing some fields so you can check which field is causing the problem?

Comment: old.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") worked! Thanks!